# Removing Robot IR Arduino Library on Macbook

Tags: osx

I'm trying to use my IR receiver on my Arduino Uno Board.  First I need to remove my IR Robot library because it interferes with the IRremote library. On my Mac, I have gone into the Arduino/library folder, but the name of the library I have to remove is not there.

I cannot figure out how to remove this. Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder name is **RobotIRremote**.

It's actually not necessary to remove that folder, though that will solve your problem. A better solution is to change the folder name of the IRremote remote library so that the file named IRremote.h found in that library will be given include priority over the one found in the RobotIRremote library. This is better because you would need to remove the RobotIRremote library every time you update to a new version of the Arduino IDE. The Arduino IDE gives include priority to files that match the name of the library folder but unfortunately if you install the IRremote library manually it will tend to have the folder name **Arduino-IRremote-master** which causes the wrong file to have priority. So you just need to find that folder and rename it **IRremote**.

If you don't know where it is the library folder can be found by:

1. File > Examples > IRremote > AiwaRCT501SendDemo
2. Sketch > Show Sketch
   Folder

Comment: So the library name for me is already IRremote, not Arduino-IRremote-master. Still not sure what to change. Also, I don't have a folder name called AiwaRCT501SendDemo under the IRremote --- instead its JVCPanasonicSendDemo.

Comment: You not having that example sketch name indicates you're using a different/outdated version of the [Arduino-IRremote library](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote). Please post a link to where you downloaded your IRremote library from. Also, please state which version of the Arduino IDE you're using. FYI, the steps to finding the library folder I posted above will work with any example from the library. I just used AiwaRCT501SendDemo because that was the first one shown on the menu for me.

Comment: Okay so I just downloaded the latest IRremote library, and it was named Arduino-IRremote-master. So all I have to do is change the name of that library to IRremote and it will work? Also, sorry for the confusion on my end, I'm just beginning with Arduino. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, change the name and replace your previous installation of the library with the new one and it should work.

Comment: It's not working. I changed the name from Arduino-IRremote-master to IRremote and removed the old IRremote, and it's not working still. Is there anything else I could be doing to make this work?

Comment: You still haven't said which version of the Arduino IDE you're using. My tests with the latest version show this should work but the behavior might be different on older IDE versions. You could always just delete the RobotIRremote library.